# Creating Excel sheet from the database using PHPExcel in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, excel, codeigniter

I am trying to create an excel sheet from the database using PHPExcel in Codeigniter for generating reports. I have the main table `sales` and more than 4 tables from which am fetching data. I have written query using multiple JOINS between the tables.

Here is my scenario:

As am dealing with generating reports for sales, A customer may have purchased multiple products and this details are stored in another table `sale_items`. At present I have written a main query with joins for other tables and after getting the result inside the foreach loop I am writing another query to select the corresponding data from `sale_items` table.

I am trying to show in excel sheet for a single customer, if he has purchased multiple products I need to show these products separated by comma in excel sheet. I used a 2nd query to fetch the product names and imploded the result and tried to show in the corresponding row in excel. it works fine if am trying it with a single customer. If I try it for more than one customer, the page shows a server error.

Here is my code:

```
    $dateTmp = "DATE_FORMAT(".$this->db->dbprefix('sales').".date,'%m/%Y')";
    $condition = "if(".$this->db->dbprefix('sales').".biller_id = 5, 'A', if(".$this->db->dbprefix('sales').".biller_id = 6, 'B',if(".$this->db->dbprefix('sales').".biller_id = 7,'C','D'  )))";       


    if ($pdf || $xls) {
    $this->db
    ->select("date, ".$this->db->dbprefix('warehouses').".name, 
    CONCAT(".$this->db->dbprefix('warehouses').".name,'-',".$dateTmp.",'-', ".$condition.",".$this->db->dbprefix('sales').".invoice_no) as month," 
    ." biller, customer,
    scan_no, CONCAT(" . $this->db->dbprefix('sale_items') . ".product_name, '__', " . $this->db->dbprefix('sale_items') . ".quantity) as iname, 
    unit_price,if(tax_rate_id=2,item_tax,0) as taxId1,if(tax_rate_id=4,item_tax,0) as taxId2 ,
    tin,cin,cst,total_discount, item_tax, shipping,subtotal,payment_status,sales.id as saleid ", FALSE)
    ->from('sales')
    ->join('sale_items', 'sale_items.sale_id=sales.id', 'left')
    ->join('companies','companies.id=sales.customer_id', 'left')
    ->join('salersperson','salersperson.id=companies.salesperson_id', 'left')
    ->join('hosipital_group','hosipital_group.id=companies.hospital_id', 'left')
    ->join('doctor','doctor.id=companies.dr_id', 'left')
    ->join('warehouses', 'warehouses.id=sales.warehouse_id', 'left')
    ->group_by('sales.id')
    ->order_by('sales.date desc');  //MAIN JOIN QUERY

    $q = $this->db->get();
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach (($q->result()) as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
    }
    } else {
    $data = NULL;
    }

    if (!empty($data)) 
    {
    $this->load->library('excel');
    $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle(lang('sales_report'));
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', lang('date'));
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B1', lang('branch'));

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', lang('invoice_no'));
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D1', lang('biller'));

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E1', lang('customer'));
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F1', lang('tin'));
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G1', lang('cin'));
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H1', lang('cst'));

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I1', lang('scan_no'));
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('J1', lang('product_qty'));
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('K1', lang('prod_price'));
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('L1', lang('vat1'));
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('M1', lang('vat2'));
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('N1', lang('discount'));
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('O1', lang('product_tax'));
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('P1', lang('shipping'));
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('Q1', lang('total'));

    $row = 2;
    $total = 0;
    $paid = 0;
    $balance = 0;

    foreach ($data as $data_row) {
    $saleid=$data_row->saleid;
    $this->db->select("product_name")
    ->from('sale_items')
    ->where('sale_items.sale_id',$saleid); /*SECOND QUERY TO FETCH FROM SALE_ITEMS TABLE*/
    $q1 = $this->db->get();
    if ($q1->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
    foreach (($q1->result()) as $row1) 
    {
    $prdtarray[] = $row1->product_name; 
    }
    $product=implode(',',$prdtarray); /*PRODUCTS NAME SEPARATED BY COMMA AND STORED IN A VARIABLE*/
    } 
    else 
    {
    $data1 = NULL;
    }

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A' . $row, $this->sma->hrld($data_row->date));
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B' . $row, $data_row->name);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C' . $row, $data_row->month);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D' . $row, $data_row->biller);

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E' . $row, $data_row->customer);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F' . $row, $data_row->tin);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G' . $row, $data_row->cin);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H' . $row, $data_row->cst);

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I' . $row, $data_row->scan_no);

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('J' . $row, $product); //THE COMMA SEPARATED PRODUCT NAMES
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('K' . $row, $data_row->unit_price);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('L' . $row, $data_row->taxId1);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('M' . $row, $data_row->taxId2);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('N' . $row, $data_row->total_discount);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('O' . $row, $data_row->item_tax);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('P' . $row, $data_row->shipping);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('Q' . $row, $data_row->subtotal);

    $total += $data_row->subtotal;
    $paid += $data_row->item_tax;
    // $balance += ($data_row->grand_total - $data_row->paid);
    $row++;
    }
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("L" . $row . ":M" . $row)->getBorders()
    ->getTop()->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_MEDIUM);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('Q' . $row, $total);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('O' . $row, $paid);
    // $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H' . $row, $balance);

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(20);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(20);

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(20);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(30);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(15);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth(15);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(15);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('H')->setWidth(20);

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('I')->setWidth(20);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('J')->setWidth(20);

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('K')->setWidth(15);

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('L')->setWidth(30);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('M')->setWidth(30);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('N')->setWidth(15);

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('O')->setWidth(30);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('P')->setWidth(30);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('Q')->setWidth(30);

    $filename = 'sales_report';
    $this->excel->getDefaultStyle()->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);

    if ($xls) {
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E2:E' . $row)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    ob_clean();
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    ob_clean();
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit();
    }

    }
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', lang('nothing_found'));
    //redirect($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);

    }
```

I don't know what happens when am trying it with more than one customer. May be Am wrong in my logic. Can anyone help me to find my mistake..?? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked server logs? What error you are getting?

Comment: i checked PHP error log and saw like this
`PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 78313 bytes) in line 1717`

Comment: line 1717 is: `$product=implode(',',$prdtarray); `

Comment: What is the size of `$prdtarray` array?

Comment: actually thats an array inside the foreach loop, you can see it in my code

Comment: Will you do `echo count($prdtarray); die;` and let me know what it will return?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100750/discussion-between-ankiig-and-aishwaryas).